# Use Default trait for struct as enum option

Tags: enums, rust, default

I have an enum like this:

```
enum States {
    A { opts: Vec<States> },
    B { opts: Vec<States> },
    C { opts: Vec<States> },
}
```

I'd like to implement the `Default` trait for it. Not for the enum itself:

```
impl Default for States {
    fn default() -> States {
        States::A { vec![] }
    }
}
```

but for `States::A`, `States::B` and `States::C`, to have default values for `opts`. Is it possible?

Comment: You `impl` for types, is any of `States::{A, B, C}` a type?

Comment: No, it's value, but aside of it `States::{A, B, C}`'s have fields that can be initialized.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is currently not possible because enum variants are not first class types. There is an open RFC that proposes "making enum variants first-class types": [RFC 1450](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1450). Until that is accepted and implemented, the workaround most people use for this is to make proper structs for each variant, and then make a simple enum wrapping those structs:

```
struct A { opts: Vec<States> }
struct B { opts: Vec<States> }
struct C { opts: Vec<States> }

enum States {
    A(A),
    B(B),
    C(C)
}
```

Then you can implement `Default` for `A`, `B`, and `C`.

```
impl Default for A {
    fn default() -> A {
        A { opts: Vec::new() }
    }
}
```

and use them as `A::default()`, `B::default()`, and `C::default()`.

Comment: Never expected Dogbert to answer my question at SO :)

Ok, thanks, seems like boilerplate for me, and makes enum variants pretty useless for such cases for now.

Comment: @BIvanov: To be honest, this is the first time that I've seen this requirement; the main benefit I had seen about struct variants was the ability to *document* the fields (`A { left_child: Node, value: T, right_child: Node }` being more self-explanatory than `A(Node, T, Node)`).

Comment: Is it possible now?

Comment: @AnatolyBugakov nope, that RFC was closed and [another simpler one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593) was opened and then resolved as "postponed" in April 2021. You can read the link for more details.